# Como llenar un select en jquery con un rango de numeros especifico

Tags: html, jquery, select, combobox

Tengo este codigo me devuelve los valores en una tabla y en la tercera columna un select que me devuelve los valores del 1 al 7, lo que quisiera es que el valor limite del select sea el numero que esta en la segunda columna de su fila correspondiente en este caso el 5.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function Pedir()
{
  console.log(localStorage.ped);
   $.ajax({
       headers:{'Authorization':'bearer '+localStorage.authentication},
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://localhost:8008/api/v1/product/"+localStorage.ped+"/product",
       contentType: 'application/json',
       success: function (response) {
           let vacio = `<tr><td colspan="4">SIN REGISTROS</td></tr>`;
           if(response.length > 0)
           {
               let filas = ``;
               $.each(response,function(i, item){
                 appendText(item)
                  var nombre = item.quantity;
                  console.log(nombre);
                   filas += `<tr><td>${item.pelicula}</td><td>${item.quantity}</td><td>
                   <select name="" id="" >
                   <option value="0">0</option>
                   <option value="1">1</option>
                   <option value="2">2</option>
                   <option value="3">3</option>
                   <option value="4">4</option>
                   <option value="5">5</option>
                   <option value="6">6</option>
                   <option value="7">7</option>
                   </select>
                   </td></tr>`;
                   console.log(item);
                   funcion();
               });
               $('#contenedor').html(filas)
           }
           else{
               $('#contenedor').html(vacio)
           }
       },
       error: function(){
           Refresh();
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es necesario que crees todo dentro del response del ajax puedes hacerlo un poco tedioso con un for pero sería algo así:

```
    appendText(item)

    /* esto sustituye desde la declaración de la variable nombre */
    var new_select = '<select name="" id="">'
    for (var i = 0; i <= item.quantity; i++) {
        new_select += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'
    }
    new_select += '</select>'

    filas += '<tr><td>${item.pelicula}</td> 
        <td>${item.quantity}</td><td>'+new_select+'</td> 
    </tr>';

    /* lo de abajo ya es tu código */
    console.log(item);
```

Quizá puedas poner más información para ver qué te conviene más, si crear el select desde ahí o solo irlo rellenando de acuerdo al valor de quantity

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¿sabes como podria sacar el valor una vez que los seleccione? ya que ambos tienen el mismo nombre.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a los selects? O sea, al select de "Thor 1" y a de "Avenger 1"? Si es así puedes agregar en esta línea un identificador al select, ya sea usando el name, id o un data-***, dependiendo de lo que mejor te convenga usar para la manipulación del elemento

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo pude solucionar.